# Crio uma tabela ou várias no SQL Server?

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, sql-server, desempenho, modelagem

Tenho as tabelas em meu banco de dados: `Orcamento`, `Maquinas`, `Veiculos` e `Acessorios`.

Preciso gravar os custos de cada uma delas, por exemplo a cada tabela será gravado um custo diariamente

Crio uma tabela chamado `Custo` ou crio uma tabela para cada um por exemplo `Custo_Orcamento`, `Custo_Maquina`, `Custo_Veiculo`, `Custo_Acessorios`?

Cada uma das 4 tabelas terão os seguintes campos:

`idCusto`, `dataCadastro`, `idProduto`, `qtd`, `vlUnitario`

Estava pensando em fazer uma única tabela chamado `Custo` e com os mesmos campos mais campos: `idDono` (1-Orcamento, 2-Maquina, 3-Veiculo e 4-Acessorio).

Queria saber se nesta onica tabela se tiver muitos dados armazenados não ficará lento para consulta do que se eu criasse 4 tabelas separadas, ou se ficaria mais organizado com as 4 do que só com uma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cada um é válido de acordo com a necessidade que não foi especificada. Modelar é entender o problema como um todo, em cada detalhe, em cada vírgula, analisando o que pode acontecer no futuro.

Ficar lento depende de como você lida com isso. Nem que sua tabelas tenhas vários terabytes ela ficará lenta se souber o que está fazendo, o que pode ser o caso já que acha que separar em tabelas é a solução para lentidão. Se o único motivo para separar é ser mais rápido, é uma decisão bem errada.

Estou considerando o modelo físico, porque o lógico nunca deve olhar dessa forma.

Se a dúvida era sobre outra coisa, aí não temos como responder por faltar informações relevantes para tomar a decisão, mas ainda parece que não faz sentido ter várias tabelas.

Comment: Legal, vou fazer uma unica tabela, Obrigado